# Update image of UIImageView in NSmutableArray?

Tags: objective-c, uiimageview

I have:

Class Piece inherit UIImageView;

```
- (void)setJumpAt:(int)frame {
NSMutableArray *ret = [SkinConstants BallSelected];
NSString *name = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"balls-%d-%d", color - 1, [[ret objectAtIndex:frame] intValue]];
UIImage *a = [UIImage imageNamed:name];
NSLog(@"%d setJumpAt: %@", self.tag ,name);
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(setImage:) withObject:a waitUntilDone:NO];
[self  setNeedsDisplay];
[self setNeedsLayout];}
```

Class Player contain NSMutableArray of Piece;

Class JumpThread contain NSTimer use to set image of Piece;

```
- (void) timer_Tick{
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
dispatch_async(queue, ^{
        [piece setJumpAt:frame++];
        [piece setNeedsDisplay];
        if (frame == len)
            frame = 0;
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    });
});}
```

I run code normal, but image of Piece not change in mainview,
Sorry, I'm not so good at English.

Comment: That last `dispatch_async()` is dispatching nothing to the main thread, and I'm not sure why you're calling `setNeedsDisplay` *and* `setNeedsLayout`. Altogether, this seems like an awkward and error-prone way of doing things - using timers and dispatching to queues and such. Have you considered using a library specifically targeting sprites and gaming, such as [SpriteKit](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/Introduction/Introduction.html)?

Comment: No, i'm not use  SpriteKit,

Answer (score 0):

`UIImageView` can animate images with an array of UIImages and suitable animationDuration

```
//self is an UIImageView instance
NSArray images = [...]; // your frames
self.animationImages = images;
self.animationDuration = 2.0f // 2.0s
[self startAnimating];
```